# Regular expression with no maximum limit

Tags: asp.net, regex, string, repeat

I Need a regular expression which accepts all types of characters (alphabets, numbers and all special characters), and miniumum number of characters should be 15 and no limit for maximum characters.

Comment: Why regex? Just check string length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.{15,}
```

Assuming that you use settings where the dot matches all characters. It's really hard to be any more specific unless you mention which platform you're using.

Comment: Hm, I guess the OP meant anything else then whitespace if I read it right, could be /^[^\s]{15,}/, which is pretty portable I think (there will always be exceptions though, so you're right to ask).

Answer (score 4):

The basic repetition options for regex are as follows:

- `x?` matches zero or one `x`
- `x*` matches zero or more `x`
- `x+` matches one or more `x`
- `x{3}` matches exactly 3 `x`
- `x{3,}` matches at least 3 `x`
- `x{3,5}` matches at least 3 and at most 5 `x`

To match absolutely any character, you use `.` in single-line mode. To enable single-line mode, consult documentation for your specific language. In Java, this is [`(?s)/Pattern.DOTALL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

If by "all types of characters" you really mean everything but whitespace, then there's a special character class for that: `\S` (with a capital `S`). The pattern you're looking for is therefore:

- `\S{15,}`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
  - [The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
  - [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ehm.. Using a regular expression when you just want to check the length of a string? Try something like

inputString.Length >= 15